# What's a single word for experience that is not extensive or deep?

Tags: single-word-requests

How do we describe an experience that is not extensive or deep but is just an initial start into something?

For example,

> I have had some ..... experience of the challenges of mobilization.

Context:

This is for a job application. The experience was quite brief that laid the initial groundwork. I am looking to use the job role that I am applying to as a sandbox to further explore the topic and I want to highlight that this experience already provides me with a solid base.

Comment: Was it brief or short in time? Was it introductory or prefatory or laying the groundwork? Was it teaching you the basics or the fundamentals or providing an overview? Was it providing a sampling or a taster? Was it uninformative or shallow or trivial?

Comment: You already have “some”. You can reduce that to “a little”, but there’s no need for a second qualifier.

Comment: For a job interview answer that is honest and positive, I'd use starter, beginner, intro, basic, or promising.

Comment: Thank you all for your reply. Yes, this is for a job application and as rightly recognised, the experience was quite brief that laid the initial groundwork. I am looking to use the job role to further explore the topic and I want to highlight that this experience already provides me that base.

Comment: @user92720 Please add **all** relevant information **to the question.** Please read the tag info for single-word-request questions.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. There's a **lot** more in the tag info which you could address.

Comment: You could give it a positive spin by saying "I've had a solid introduction to [subfield] etc."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could describe your experience as **[Basic:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/basic)**

> constituting or serving as the basis or starting point
> *<sub>from [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/basic)</sub>*

Answer (score 1):

**Shallow** -> MW -. : lacking in depth of knowledge, thought, or feeling.

**Superficial** ->MW 2a: concerned only with the obvious or apparent : SHALLOW

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It seems to me that these words have a negative connotation. I am looking for a word to describe an introductory experience that is relevant for my future career. This is for the context of a job application

Comment: That context, absent in the original, was important...

Answer (score 0):

Apprentice.

I would use it has a sort of compound word to communicate the concept clearly:

"I have had apprentice-level experience with the challenges of mobilization."

Answer (score 0):

Consider **introductory**, which means "serving as an introduction", with "introduction" in the sense of

> A course of study preliminary and preparatory to some special study; matter introductory to the special study of some subject.  (OED)

This conveys that your experience could serve as a base from which you are now prepared to delve into the subject in-depth.